How do I set the amount of gas when deploying a contract - ethers.rs?
I have this function for contract deployment:
    async fn _deploy_contract(
    network: &str,
    contract_path: &str,
    constructor_args: Option<Vec<Token>>,    
    ) -> Result<Address> {
    
    let (client, abi, bytecode) = init(&contract_path, &network)?;
    
    // Create a contract factory
    let factory = ContractFactory::new(abi, bytecode.into(), client);

    // Convert the vector of tokens to a tuple for deployment
    let contract = if let Some(args) = constructor_args {
        match args.len() {
            1 => {
                factory.deploy(args[0].clone())?.send().await?
            }
            4 => {
                let args = (args[0].clone(), args[1].clone(), args[2].clone(), args[3].clone());
                factory.deploy(args)?.send().await?
            }
            _=> {
                panic!("Incorrect number of arguments!");
            }
        }        
    } else {        
        factory.deploy(())?.send().await?;        
    };

    Ok(contract.address())
}

Can you please tell me how to set the amount of gas for deployment?
I've tried doing something like this:
factory.deploy(())?.gas_price(10000000).gas_limit(10000000000000).send().await?;
but it doesn't work that way.
In general, the need to set gas parameters arises when I try to deploy on polygon and bsc blockchains, this is not the case with ethereum.
